# How to dump a PDF generated in Oracle clob?

Tags: java, clob

I have a method generating a PDF - generatePDF(SomeParams).

The PDF created should be dumped into a clob of an oracle table.

What is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: You want the text inside the PDF stored in a CLOB, or the whole PDF stored in a BLOB?

Comment: **simplest way**, googling first before ask any question.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

Comment: Also please be specific about the code used - what is the "pdf" that your method returns? What type is it, from which API?

Comment: @kayaman - the whole PDF to be stored. Pardon my ignorance, for saving file we need blob. cant save as clob?

Comment: Well, open up a pdf file in notepad and tell me if you're seeing **C**haracter data or **B**inary data.

Comment: %PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
3 0 obj
endobj
5 0 obj
[1 0 R/XYZ 0 852 0]
endobj
2 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/
4 0 obj
R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/AppDefault>>/Pages 4 0 R>>
endobj
9 0 obj
endobj
xref
0 10
0000001482 00000 n 
0000001359 00000 n 
<</Root 8 0 R/ID [<5ddd7c6da835b0fa56f4434109953fba><86936590f3b7446080c2f64fffdccf13>]/Info 9 0 R/Size 10>>
startxref
1907
%%EOF

Answer (score 0):

You can use bfile.

this can help you: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:232814159006

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide a summary of what's in the link?